# lotus notes - scheduled replication not working

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

This question may seem like a strange one, but here what I noticed with our admin: we have an application which we want replicate scheduled it. All the docs. from this app, after the replication, are gone/deleted. Our admin noticed from the log file that the server where the replication takes place didn't have enough rights.

Creating a manual replication works just fine ( pull - push ), without any problems.

What could be the reasons?

BTW: we also replicate other applications, using scheduled replication, but it is working OK, without issues. So, what does this application have which "block" the scheduled replication and which cause the document to be deleted?

Comment: This question is about coding as well, as most probably the reader fields in the application are not properly filled... But I agree: As it is at the moment, it would better fit to "serverfault".

Answer (score 2):

You answered your question already by yourself: The server that replicates does not have enough rights: Most probably the server is not member of any of the readers- fields in the documents. When replicating the server "sees" that it should not "see" any of the documents, and removes them from the database (NOT DELETE, because deletion would create deletion stubs).

If you manually replicate a database, then replication is done with the rights of the person, who starts it: This person seems to have the right permissions...